# How to get pages to open in the same browser window from different async functions using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have two different functions (`openbrowser` and `open` in the code sample below) that open pages using puppeteer. I want both functions to open their pages in the same browser window. Currently, when each function is called, each opens a new browser window.

```
let openbrowser = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({
    width: 1280,
    height: 800,
    isMobile: false,
  });
  await page.goto("https://youtube.com/");
};

let open = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({
    width: 1280,
    height: 800,
    isMobile: false,
  });
  await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=avatar");
};

openbrowser()
open()
```

Even if `open` just calls `openbrowser`, it still launches a new browser to open the page.

```
let open = async () => {
    openbrowser()
};
```

How can I make different functions open URLs in the same browser window?

Comment: Open one browser, then open multiple pages within it. The browser should always be closed with a `.finally` block somewhere.

Comment: i dont really get what you mean. i want the link in `openbrowser` to open when i call from `open` function (eg from youtube.com -> from that link go redirect to 'avatar' search result)

Comment: I don't get what you mean either, sorry. What is the problem here? I'm not sure how else to phrase it--open one browser and then open multiple pages on that single browser. If you call `puppeteer.launch()` in each function, you'll get a new browser per call. That's probably not what you want. Maybe try adding parameters to functions. Close all resources you open or your script will hang. These functions need to either close or return the browser handle so someone can take care of it. `page.setViewport` needs to be `await`ed.

Answer (score 1):

You open two browsers and two pages, hence you get two pages.

Simply reuse the same browser and page (aka browser tab) to navigate to the next page:

```
let openbrowser = async () => {
  // initialize:
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800, isMobile: false, });

  // load first page:
  await page.goto("https://youtube.com/");
  // do stuff with this page, such as: await page.screenshot()

  // navigate to next page:
  await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=avatar");

  // after all done:
  await page.close();
  await sleep(2000);
  await browser.close();
};

(async() => {
  openbrowser();
})();
```

**UPDATE**

You can split this code up into functions, simply pass along the `page` object:

```
const loadPage1 = async (page) => {
  await page.goto("https://youtube.com/");
  // do stuff with this page, such as: await page.screenshot()
};

const loadPage2 = async (page) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=avatar");
  // do other stuff
};

let browser;
(async() => {
  // initialize:
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800, isMobile: false });

  loadPage1(page); // load first page
  loadPage2(page); // navigate to next page

  // after all done:
  await page.close();
  await sleep(2000);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: this is the output that i want, but can it be made into two separate function? because i want the function 1 to be located outside of npm cron function, and function 2 to be put inside of cron function

Comment: @UltraRocket: Yes, you can split this code up into functions, simply pass along the page object. See **UPDATE**

Comment: @UltraRocket: Does this answer your question? If so would you care to accept it (see gray checkmark)? If not, please add some more details to your question.